# Override PrimeFaces' MediaRenderer

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Im trying to override Primeface's 7.0 MediaRenderer, I created my own MyMediaRenderer with Primeface's 8.0 method:

```
public class MyMediaRenderer extends org.primefaces.component.media.MediaRenderer {
   @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
    ...
       if (value instanceof StreamedContent && PDFPlayer.MIME_TYPE.equals(player.getType())) {
       ...
       }
    ...
   }
   
}
```

I also added to the end of src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml :

```
    <render-kit>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>org.primefaces.component.media</component-family>
            <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.media.MediaRenderer</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>redacted.MyMediaRenderer</renderer-class>
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>

</faces-config>
```

What am I missing here? The method is still called from org.primefaces.component.media.MediaRenderer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your renderkit is incorrect use the following:

```xml
<renderer>
       <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
       <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.MediaRenderer</renderer-type>
       <renderer-class>redacted.MyMediaRenderer</renderer-class>
</renderer>
```

Comment: @ActionAdi please select my answer then as solving your issue.